# Should I be concerned about my bell peppers

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, bell-peppers

Started Bell Peppers from seeds may 7 indoors, transplanted them a few weeks ago, I'm in USDA zone 5.

They don't seem to be growing too well, in terms of bushing out and growing taller. 
Here is a pic.

[image]

The other 11 I have growing look more or less similar to this one ( some a bit more foliage) and 3 of them have even started fruiting with very tiny marble sized peppers on them as of a few days. Should I be worried at the lack of height and bushiness? How to fix the problem? I think I had them too long in small containers so that might be part of it.I can take more pictures and closer up if that will help people determine too.

Comment: How small were they when you planted them out? They look healthy to me. When I plant seedlings out, they take a few weeks to really start growing. Here in Texas, a drip system has also really helped my peppers...

Comment: I haven't measured with a ruler but they were maybe 5 inches and now 7? On average, some have grown maybe 1 inch more and some half an inch less but that is a pretty good estimate

Comment: Too much nitrogen will stunt peppers. I know it's been a weird year in the US, but yours should be much larger by now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the *transplanted them a few weeks ago*.

Transplanting is a shock for the plant, and changing from indoor to outdoor is also a shock.  Normal, most of plants will have this, but you should not expect to get quickly a growth. Now the plants will form new roots, adapt to the environment (and sun). Give them some time and they will growth.

Maybe next year: try to seed them in February/March. May is somehow late. You will get fruits, but just later on summer/autumn.

I see no problems on your plants.

Comment: Agree. Planting out and fruiting will depend on climate. When using seed, I sow in Jan, and try to plant out aftet the last frost. Put seedlings outside in the afternoons before planting out so they acclimate. Summer is often too hot for fruit, but usually get something in May/June.

Comment: I see okay, this all makes sense. I did harden them off but could've probably done so over a longer period of time.